# React: Child Component div is also applied to sibling. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

This is the render method of one of my components:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="left col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <Dropdown show={this.state.showDropdown}/>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It's just a div with a full screen dropdown menu, and some children. When `showDropdown===true`, the dropdown menu is shown. Now in one of the pages in which this component is used, the immediate child has a some issues with formatting, so I included a `padding: 50px`. This solved the issue. But now my Dropdown component also gets the padding of 50px, which moves my Dropdown Menu Items down and ruins the formatting of the Dropdown - but I don't know why? Is this normal behaviour?

CSS of the parent:

```
.left {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  // background-color: MediumSpringGreen;
  background-color: $color_left;

  height: auto;
  min-height: 100vh;

  z-index: 1;
  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    height: 100vh;
  }
}
```

Code of child

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="row">
    <Loader show={this.state.loading} />
    <Left> 
      <div className="about_padding">
        <p className="red big-box-text-two">Text text text</p>
        <a className="menu-link statementbox" id="menu-statement" href="./pdf/statement.pdf" download="statement.pdf">
          <p className="menu-link-text">our statement</p>
          <img className="img-fluid download-img" src={imgDownload} alt="download"></img>
        </a>
      </div>
    </Left>
}
```

CSS of the child:

```
.statementbox {
  margin-top: 20px !important;
}

.about_padding {
  padding-left: 15%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  //I was trying to add padding-top here, but it also pushes down my Dropdown

  @include media-breakpoint-down(xs) {
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 10%;
  }
}
```

Code of the Dropdown:

```
const Dropdown = ({show}) => 
<div className="dropdown"
style={{
        visibility: show ? "visible" : "hidden",
        opacity: show ? 1 : 0
        }}>
  <Link to="/">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/menus/">Menus</Link>
  <Link to="/about/">About us</Link>
  <Link to="/contact/">Contact</Link>
</div>
```

CSS of the Dropdown:

```
.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;

  font-size: 40px; 
  background-color: #FFD826; 
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;

  a {
    color: #f42528 !important; 
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the css and what is the generated DOM ? Looks like a simple CSS issue instead, of course, if I missed your point.

Comment: As @3Dos said, you are most likely applying the same style to both components, make sure you use unique class names all over your application stylesheets or use an alternative to encapsulate your CSS like [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)

Comment: Thanks! I edited the post to include everything. I don't think I am applying the same class to the other component, but I'm happy to be proven wrong.